# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kilobolt.tweenaccessors.SpriteAccessor

Tags: android, libgdx

I set up the Project with LibGDX gradle and everything worked fine until i addet Tween Engine Library to our libGDX projects

Here is my problem. I just want to make a splash screen with libgdx But my codes doesn 't work and here is LogCat about error.

```
06-27 04:23:45.778    1116-1130/com.kilobolt.zombiebird.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 95
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kilobolt.tweenaccessors.SpriteAccessor
            at com.kilobolt.screens.SplashScreen.setupTween(SplashScreen.java:47)
            at com.kilobolt.screens.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:42)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
            at com.kilobolt.zombiebird.ZBGame.create(ZBGame.java:18)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Firstly i wrote codes and that 's work without any problem. But i added some tween codes and now it doesn 't work.

my project convert from eclipse to android studio.

My build.gradle looks like this :

```
    apply plugin: "java"
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]
eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}

dependencies {
    compile files('tween-engine-api.jar')
    compile files('tween-engine-api-sources.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add dependencies to `tween-engine-api.jar` and `tween-engine-api-sources.jar` to every starter module as well.